# Is there a way to pass a method name to a function, and have that function return a delegate encapsulating that method?

Tags: c#, delegates

I want to pass a method ( Foo ) to a function which returns an action ( or a delegate ) ( Bar ) and have that function construct a new Action ( or delegate ) : Like when a delegate is declared :

```
delegate FooDelegate( );
```

and then you can say

```
//In this case, Foo is a method name which has been passed to a constructor.
FooDelegate MyFooDelegate = new FooDelegate( Foo );
```

So rather than having to say

```
FooDelegate VarNameHere = new FooDelegate( MethodNameHere );
```

I would like to be able to say

```
FooDelegate VarNameHere = MyFooDelegator( MethodNameHere )
```

and have MyFooDelegator be a function which returns a delegate of type ***Whatever*** ( the type is not relevant to the question ) :

```
public FooDelegate MyFooDelegator( method MethodToFooDelegate ){
    return new FooDelegate( MethodToFooDelegate );
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The purpose of your `Bar` method is unclear to me.  Wouldn't you want it to simply execute `MethodToDelegate`?

Comment: `(Action MethodToDelegate)` but in this way you can only use method groups and there must be parameterless void method available...

Comment: @sstan ... This example does ***NOT*** illustrate anything beyond the behaviour for which I am looking.

Comment: Reworded question to more accurately reflect what I am asking...

Comment: _This example does NOT illustrate anything beyond the behaviour for which I am looking_ ..... please illustrate because you are in kind of a limit here...

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to wrap arbitrary methods into your helper function (similar to interception behavior of many dependency injections frameworks like [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx)).

Indeed it is possible - the easiest way would be have several functions that wrap 0-n argument functions:

```
Func<TResult> Wrap<TResult>(Func<TResult> inner)
{
     return () => 
          {
             //BeforeCall();   
             var r = inner();
             //AfterCall(); 
             return r;
          };        
}

Func<TArg1, TResult> Wrap<TArg1, TResult>(Func<TArg1, TResult> inner)
{
     return (arg1) => 
          {
             //BeforeCall();   
             var r = inner(arg1);
             //AfterCall(); 
             return r;
          };        
}
```

And use like:

```
// int R1(int z){return 42;}
var wrapped = Wrap(MethodNameHere);     
var wrappedOneArg = Wrap<int,int>(R1);
```

You can also write code to construct more generic wrappers, but you likely will need to use expression trees or even direct IL building.

Note: recent versions of C# (3+?) allow to pass method name where in older versions you'd need to cast to delegate.

Comment: So the argument type furnished to a method so that you can pass it a method is literally Func or Action? Okay very cool - that's exactly what I needed to know. Awesome; thanks.